# Update field with data from another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Need to update a field with data from another field in a different database

I Have two SQL commercial Databases from the same company, the first Database has one field that is null in the other

I need to update the Field/Database that is null with the data of the first one.

Comment: You will need to add a little information. At a very minimum, which databases?

Comment: What server? What's the problem? What's the question?

Comment: I Have two SQL comercial Databases from the same company, the first Databases has one field that is null in the other, need to update the Database that was null field with the data of the first one.

Comment: `sql` is not the same as `sql-server`. `sql` is a generic tag.

Comment: Sorry made a typing mistake... I Have two SQL comercial Databases from the same company, the first Database has one field that is null in the other, need to update the Field/Database that is null with the data of the first one.

Answer (score 70):

**MS SQL Server**

Update table1 in current database from table1 in database called "DataBaseName"

```
update table1
set col2 = T2.col2
from DataBaseName.dbo.table1 as T2
  where table1.ID = T2.ID and
        table1.col2 is null
```

Comment: @MikeRTeixeira: By marking Mikael's answer as *accepted* you will prove yourself not only polite but also a diligent and careful member of the community. :)

Comment: @AndriyM I just don't agree that with doing that he will be polite, because not accepting it will not make him impolite. I think you mean will be nice :)